# DBMS_JOB usage: 'Singular' job keeps recurring every five seconds

Tags: oracle, triggers, jobs, job-scheduling

I learned (the hard way) that DDL statements cannot be executed in the non-transactional context of a logon trigger, and that the solution is a job. I want the job to be executed **immediately and one single time** and therefore set the `next_date` parameter to `sysdate` and the `interval` parameter to `null`.

Here is what I execute in the trigger:

```
dbms_job.submit(
  job=>jobNumber, 
  what=>'someProcedure(someParameter);',
  next_date=>sysdate,
  interval=>null
);
```

This works quite good, but once the trigger has been fired (and the above command has been submitted) for the time, the audit log shows that the job keeps reappearing exactly every five seconds under the same user account it has been submitted under for the first time. The associated program is always something like `ORACLE.EXE (J001)`, although it was of course a user session initiated from a client application.

Can anyone explain this to me please? I hoped to get a singular execution of the job and not an eternal recurrence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the user is not in fact logging on multiple times?

Comment: [The `DBMS_JOB` package has been superseded by the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm). Might as well work with that rather than make something older work?

Comment: One explanation might be that the job is failing (that is, is raising an unhandled exception).  When this happens, `DBMS_JOB` tries re-run the job a number of times.  The `USER_JOBS`, `ALL_JOBS`, and/or `DBA_JOBS` data dictionary views (particularly the `FAILURES` column) might have some clues.